# List Items are showing up inside my submit button in to-do app

Tags: javascript

My List items are showing up inside of my submit button when I submit a new task.
EXPECTATION: when the submit button is clicked a new task should show up in a task list inside the .
ACTUAL: submit button is clicked, a new task is made inside of the submit button.

```
        <body>
            <div class="container">
             <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
             <form id="taskForm">
               <input id="taskInput"></input>
               <button type="button" id="taskButton" onclick="taskList()">
               Click Here</buton>  
               </form>
          </div>
          <div>
            <ul id="taskLister"></ul> 
          </div>
        
           <script src=script.js></script>
        </body>

        
        function taskList() {
            let item = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
            let text = document.createTextNode(item);
            let newTask = document.createElement("li");
            let deleteTask = document.createElement("button");
          deleteTask.style.cssText = 'height: 30px; width: 60px;';
          deleteTask.innerText = 'Delete';
          newTask.appendChild(text);
          deleteTask.appendChild(newTask);
          document.getElementById("taskLister").appendChild(newTask);
          }
```

Comment: It's because of the `</buton>` misspelling

Comment: Spelling </button> right fixed it.

Comment: That did work too but I did still had to fix the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstable the `<input>` HTML element has no closing tag and you have misspelled the closing tag name `</button>`

```js
function taskList() {
  let item = document.getElementById("taskInput").value;
  let text = document.createTextNode(item);
  let newTask = document.createElement("li");
  let deleteTask = document.createElement("button");
  deleteTask.style.cssText = 'height: 30px; width: 60px;';
  deleteTask.innerText = 'Delete';
  newTask.appendChild(text);
  deleteTask.appendChild(newTask);
  document.getElementById("taskLister").appendChild(newTask);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
  <form id="taskForm">
    <input id="taskInput">
    <button type="button" id="taskButton" onclick="taskList()">Click Here</button>  
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <ul id="taskLister"></ul> 
</div>
```

I thought you want to add a remove button to each list item so here is an example

```js
function taskList() {
  // using inner HTML is much clear and gives a cleaner code
  document.getElementById("taskLister").innerHTML += `
    <li>${document.querySelector("#taskInput").value}<button onclick="this.parentElement.remove()">&times;</button></li>
  `;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>TO DO LIST</h1>
  <form id="taskForm">
    <input id="taskInput">
    <button type="button" id="taskButton" onclick="taskList()">Click Here</button>  
  </form>
</div>

<div>
  <ul id="taskLister"></ul> 
</div>
```